# IIS7 apppool auto recycling causing upload issues

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, application-pool, recycle

We have our main apppool on auto recycle every 10 minutes or so.  Unfortunately at the moment this is a necessity to keep the site stable as there appear to be various issues causing this to be necessary.

The problem is that we've released an important feature of our site that allows users to upload large files (>200mb).  If the apppool recycles during that time which it often does, the upload fails and they  get a 500 server error.

Assuming we are unable to currently change the recycle settings, what's the best way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a lot of choices if you have no ability to change to the IIS settings.  Some things I can think of:

- Upload to a simple, secondary application that does not need to be recycled
- Upload to Amazon S3 or some other cloud-based storage provider and have your back-end retrieve the file from there when it is able.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the App Pool is auto recycling every 10 minutes because you are hitting a certain amount of errors within a certain amount of time; commonly known as [Rapid Fail Protection.](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure)

Now if you look on that page you can see how to increase the failure & time limits to avoid the application pool restarting sporadically.

Without being able to change your auto recycling I suggest you find out why your application is failing so often and needing to recycle the application pool. You could use something like NewRelic to do so, but then if you have access to do that then you'd be able to change the recycle settings.

Comment: I just check RFP, and it's off on the web server (appears to always have been off).  It's been a while since I changed IIS settings so I will increase the recycling time from 30 mins to 1 hour and see if it's OK.